# Confused between expectation and conditional expectation

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I am trying to understand Example 4.16 from the book Introduction to Probability by  Dimitri Bertsekas and John Tsitsiklis:

> We are given a biased coin and we are told that because of
> manufacturing defects, the probability of heads, denoted by $Y$, is
> itself random, with a known distribution over the interval $[0, 1]$.
> We toss the coin a fixed number $n$ of times, and we let $X$ be the
> number of heads obtained. Then, for any $y \in [0, 1 ]$, we have
> $\mathbb{E} [X | Y = y ] = ny$, so $\mathbb{E} [X | Y]$ is the random
> variable $nY$.

Why is it necessary to condition on $Y$ here? Why can't we just write $\mathbb{E}[X] = nY$? My reasoning is that even if we don't know the value of $Y$, we can still write $\mathbb{E}[X]$ as a function of the random variable $Y$. I am not able to understand the flaw in my reasoning. I would be grateful if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: $X$ is Binomially distributed $\mathcal{B}(n, y)$ conditional on $Y=y$. The unconditional distribution must be found and from that one can compute $E(X)$ and see it is not $nY$ but rather $n/2$ (or just use the law of total expectation). Does that help clarify briefly?

Comment: @NapD.Lover Yes, this matches with the explanation given in the book. I understand why it is correct, but I am not able to understand why my reasoning is wrong.

Comment: Recall that $E(X)=\int x f_X(x) dx$ while $E(X|Y)=\int x f_{X|Y}(x|y) dx$. These are not necessarily the same unless $X$ is independent of $Y$. You are given the conditional PDF and you can compute $f_X(x)=\int_y f(x|y)f_Y(y) dy$. You cannot write $E(X)$ as a function of $y$ consequently because it is integrated out. Does that tackle the issue better?

Comment: Yes, this makes sense. Can we generalize this and say that the unconditional expectation must be a number, and cannot be a function of any random variable?

Comment: Indeed, unconditional expectations average out all randomness. The only functional dependence that can result is through a deterministic parameter e.g. defining a function $g(a)=E(f(X, a))$ provided the expectation exists and is finite for each $a\in A\subset \mathbb{R}$ where $f: \mathbb{R}\times A \to \mathbb{R}$ is a given (nice) function. This is a typical situation in stochastic control where one optimizes the resulting function $g$ over $a\in A$ but all randomness is gone and one is back to deterministic calculus.

Comment: If you would like, feel free to summarize our comments into an answer to your own question (which is totally allowed and encouraged on this site, by the way) if not I may do so later, for completeness.